# format the output from "x days xx:xx:xx" to "xx:xx" (timedelta64[ns] in minutes)

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, timedelta

I have a dataframe, in which I created a new column referring to the duration between two dates:

> df['test'] = ((df['data_1'] - df['data_2'])

out:
**1 days 00:10:00**

However, I need the output format to be:

**34:00**

Desired timedelta64[ns] in minutes

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not in English

Comment: this site is for english questions, please re-post at the language appropiate version of stackoverflow

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yuca and Marcin Orlowski , sorry! Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide a working example?

Unfortunately, you cant access the total hours directly. However, what you can use is `.total_seconds()` and calculate the hours and minutes like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'data_1': {0: '2022-09-22 00:00:00',
                              1: '2022-09-22 00:00:00'},
                   'data_2': {0: '2022-09-23 00:01:00',
                              1: '2022-09-24 05:00:00'}})
df['data_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data_1'])
df['data_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data_2'])
df['test'] = df['data_2'] - df['data_1']


def format_timedelta(td):
    return f"{td.days:02d}:{int(td.total_seconds()//3600):02d}"

df['test'].apply(format_timedelta)
```

or in one line using a lambda function:

```
df['test'].apply(lambda row: f"{row.days:02d}:{int(row.total_seconds()//3600):02d}")
```

Comment: that's awasome,  it's works!! Thank u so much! @bitflip